# Laser etched logo in glass

Tags: materials, uv, glass

I've tried everything found online, and suggested in forums but can't seem to achieve the realism I need.
I'm looking to etch a logo and text in a whisky bottle which will not only create translucent glass, but will lighten the area. The problem I have is adding the layer to the existing material and making it look convincing. I've tried different masks, layers, etc. with no success. Below is a photo of what I'm trying to create, and the my work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
**This is the real bottle...**
[image: Original]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are a few ways you can achieve this. One way is to create a suitable mask from your base image (The one with the double D logo") using an *RGB to BW* node and a *ColorRamp*, and use that as a mask between a normal (unaltered) *Glass Shader* and another *Glass Shader* that has had it's Normal, Roughnes, IOR (or any combination of the 3) "warped" by a *Noise Texture*:

[image: GlassFrost]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll give it a shot and report my results.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherBennett, Your solution worked perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear it works - if you want to improve over my example, up the Noise detail to 16, increase the scale a bit and increase the mix with white on the MixRGB node to .98 or so (makes it more subtle/realistic).